# How to merge two .a files which is built for armv7 and i386?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, static-libraries

I have 2 static library(.a) files. These 2 files are basically same library.
one is built for architecture armv7, another one is built for architecture i386.
Is it possible to merge these 2 libraries into 1 file?
Unfortunately, I don't have any source code to re-build them.

Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to get to know what can be done with the `lipo` and `libtool` command line tools, both of which come with Xcode.

[Here's a tutorial that might get you started](https://cvursache.com/2013/10/06/Combining-Multi-Arch-Binaries.html) on the process.

The steps include something like:

1. `lipo -info libFirst.a libSecond.a` find out what architectures are in the .a files
2. `lipo -extract armv7s libFirst.a -o libFirst_armv7s.a` extract the architectures you want
3. `libtool -static libFirst_armv7.a libSecond_armv7.a -o libCombined_armv7.a` combine the architecture specific .a files into one
4. `lipo -create libCombined_armv7.a libCombined_armv7s.a -o libCombined.a` and this gives you the final .a library.

And here's [some older documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/building_files.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001828-96838-BABBHEIC) which describes how to use the tools to create combined static libraries.

Comment: I just edited the link because it wasn't correct.  Here is the url if anyone else is interested.  It really helped me out https://cvursache.com/2013/10/06/Combining-Multi-Arch-Binaries.html

Comment: Also `lipo -info` command gives information whether a library archive is fat or not. This means that if the archive files you are about to combine are not fat you can use the #4 directly.

Comment: is there a tool similar to lipo for linux?